# Fake.app: How to loop thru the rows in a CSV file and use the data in my Workflow?

Tags: script, web-browsing, web-browser, fake.app

I am using [Fake](http://fakeapp.com) to automate some web tasks.

I have a CSV file on disk that contains rows of data which I'd like to use to fill out forms in my Fake Workflow.

How can I iterate thru the rows in the CSV file and access the values found in each column in my Fake Workflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is to use the **Repeat With** Action with the **lines in file** option selected. This allows you to read the CVS file on disk and iterate thru the rows as **Fake Variables**. You can then access these Fake Variables in other Actions which can fill out the web form (or whatever you need).

[image]

As seen in the screenshot above, I'm using a **Do JavaScript** action to initially fetch the current `line` Variable and then split it into an array of comma separated values.

```
var line = fake.get('line');
```

Then I use Fake's JavaScript API to set individual variables for each column:

```
var row = line.split(',');
fake.set('first', row[0]);
fake.set('last', row[1]);
```

Then use other Fake Actions to work with the data you've fetched. In this case, I'll fill out a simple web form using the **Set Value of HTML Element** Action. In this Action's text fields you can access Fake Variables with this special syntax:

```
${first}
```