# How to get Fake.app to return 2 types of OSX notification?

Tags: notifications, automation, fake.app

I am trying to automate a 'title' search on Amazon (kindle category) using Fake.app.  The search is conducted every week for about 100 titles. I followed the below 2 posts from Fake.App developer and I am stuck.

**Question 1**
I have created the workflow and it loops through successfully grabbing the title from my text file.

**How do I return a progress message via OSX notification?**  I want to return "searching for ${Title}", where Titles is held in a variable

[image: current workflow step, notification shows growl not OSX notifications]

**Question 2** 
How do I check the search page results to see if it contains ${Title} (e.g. found the book), and return Book found ${Title}?  I am not sure if this is even possible using Fake.App.

I have found a Firefox Browser and Cloud App (Distill.io) that does this (monitors a web page based on text criteria). Distrill.io does have an api ( but I do not know if Fake.App can do this or I have to work out how to call this api to do this step. The result I would like to return via OSX notification if possible.

[image: current workflow]
**Post 1**
How to force Fake.app to connect an HTML element by XPath (instead of “id” attribute)
[How to force Fake.app to connect an HTML element by XPath (instead of "id" attribute)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82067/how-to-force-fake-app-to-connect-an-html-element-by-xpath-instead-of-id-attri/82068#82068)

**Post 2**
Fake.app: How to loop thru the rows in a CSV file and use the data in my Workflow?
[Fake.app: How to loop thru the rows in a CSV file and use the data in my Workflow?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52236/fake-app-how-to-loop-thru-the-rows-in-a-csv-file-and-use-the-data-in-my-workflo/52237#52237)

Answer (score 1):

The Wait for Condition action will allow you to check the page's title. Add the action to your workflow at the bottom, and chose the "Title Equals" option; then you can but the variable ${Title} into that action.

[image: Wait for Condition]